# Find rotation matrix to match points in parallel projection

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, rotations, orthogonality, least-squares

I am given two sets of 3D points (actually 2D, see below) with corresponding pairs.
I am seeking two 3D rotation matrices, such that (only) the X and Y components of the rotated points match best (they won't match exactly).
Additionally, I am given the remaining Z distance for each pair of points.

All given points in both sets lie in a plane (w.l.o.g in the XY plane)

So for each pair of points $a_1$ and $b_1$:

[image: Eq. 1]

(red variables are given)

I could also reformulate this as having only one rotation matrix but instead an unknown direction shift vector with known length:

[image: Eq. 2]

(where length of the $v$ vector is 1)

Comment: In other words, you want to rotate point $b_1$ around the origin, so that its distance from point $a_1$ becomes equal to $d_1$. But that can be done only if $||a_1|-|b_1||\le d_1 \le |a_1|+|b_1|$.

Comment: Yes, the second equation is somehow like that. However, I want to find a common shift vector v for all point pairs! Hence it is not just the distance which is important but also the direction